# How to show range of cells from one sheet in another with formating

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, formula

I have a document with several sheets.

Each sheet has a range of cells (on the same row, spanning multiple columns) that are specific to that sheet (sheet "description").

I want to make a "table of contents" sheet that shows the name of each sheet and next to it, show the above mentioned range of cells as they are in each sheet.

I've tried with `=ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!C2:AJ2)` and with `=IMPORTRANGE("sheet-ID"; "Sheet1!C2:AJ2")`, but both of them brin in just the cell data, not their formating.

The formating includes: cell merging, font, background color.

How could I mirror on the "Table of contents" sheet, the "description cell range" of each sheet?"

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by using formulas. Instead you should use [copyTo(Range)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)) or [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-options) methods from Google Apps Script.

Comment: I cannot use `copyTo()` because `You do not have the permission to call copyTo`. And I've searched for the whole day on how to solve the permission problem without any luck.

Comment: I think that you are trying to use copyTo() in a custom function, that implies the use of a formula. As I said in the answer, this is not possible. You call the function from the Script Editor or by using a trigger (custom menu, on Open, on Edit a time driven trigger...) If your require further help on this, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late, but for new visitors.

You can use [sort function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en). Simply add a sorted column to your range. Then sort the whole range again on your new sheet by the new column.